# Add CSS class with Javascript based on assigned values

Tags: javascript, css

I have a web-based crm and am trying to edit the layout of a particular page. I want to add a class using javascript depending on the values of "created_by_name" is the same as "assigned_user_name".

Here's the javascript...

```
<script>
    var assigneduser = document.getElementById("<%= model.get('created_by_name') %>").value;
    var createdby = document.getElementById("<%= model.get('assigned_user_name') %>").value;

    if (assigneduser === createdby) {
        document.getElementById("eachmessage").className += " message to";


    } else {
        document.getElementById("eachmessage").className += " message from";
    }
</script>
```

Here's the complete code.

```
<script>
    var assigneduser = document.getElementById("<%= model.get('created_by_name') %>").value;
    var createdby = document.getElementById("<%= model.get('assigned_user_name') %>").value;

    if (assigneduser === createdby) {
        document.getElementById("eachmessage").className += " message to";


    } else {
        document.getElementById("eachmessage").className += " message from";
    }
</script>
<% var rowsOnly = (rowsOnly != 'undefined' && rowsOnly) %>
<% if (!rowsOnly) { %>
<div class="messages-wrapper">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" id="list-view">
    <% } %>
    <% if (collection.length > 0) { %>
    <%
    _.each(collection.models, function(model, key) {
    %>  
    <li name="eachmessage" class="">
        <h5><%= model.get('name') %>&nbsp;</h5>                 
        <p><%= model.get('created_by_name') %>&nbsp;</p>                    
        <p><%= model.get('description') %>&nbsp;</p>                    
        <p><%= helper.getDateTime().convertToDisplayDate(model.get('date_entered')) %>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><%= model.get('assigned_user_name') %>&nbsp;</p>                 
        <a data-icon="arrow-r" href="#<%= collection.module %>/create" data-theme="c"><%= helper.string('New') %></a>
    </li>
    <% }); %>
    <% } else { %>
    <li> <%= helper.string('You have no messages.') %></li>
    <% } %>
    <% if (!rowsOnly) { %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Can someone help me understand how to correctly call for the values of `created_by_name` and `assigned_user_name` so I can compare and apply css as needed.

Or, if there is a better way to do this using something other than javascript, let me know.

Comment: In your JavaScript, you're looking for an element with `id="eachmessage"` but in your html, you have an element where `name="eachmessage"`.  Assuming that there is more than one model in your collection, using ids wouldn't work because they must be unique.   Add a class to your `li`, then iterate through each one and compare the names in that list and then either apply the class inside that iteration.

Comment: @larz, I see the error with using id versus name. But I'm not sure how to accomplish the rest of what your comment suggests ("then iterate through each one and compare the names in that list and then either apply the class inside that iteration"). Can you provide specifics?